# Minimum questions to find sorted sequence

Tags: graph-theory, game-theory

Suppose two players A,B play a game.Person A knows a tuple of numbers in which the numbers can repeat ,let that tuple be $(x_{1},x_{2} ....,x_{n})=S$.Person B must try to identify sorted sequence of these numbers and he doesn't know them,no matter how long and he can ask A if $x_{i} \le x_{j} $ where $i,j$ are different.First person B asks questions and after all questions have been asked A tells him the answer to his questions.Then B for sure must know a sorted sequence of these numbers ,so the question is what is the minimum amount of questions B should ask?I am seeking a solution with a graph,I came up with the idea that if each number is vertex then we should try to find if this graph is connected which is known that the lower bound is $Ω(n^2)$,is my approach correct or is there a better one?

Answer (score 1):

There are only $\frac12(n^2-n)$ pairs, so that is the most questions you need to ask.  If you have to specify the questions before getting any answers, you need all of them because any pair could be neighbors in the order.  If you can react to the data you get, there are [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) like heapsort that are $O(n \log n)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer but if I had to prove for example that the lower bound is $Ω(n^2)$ can it be done as :create a graph with n nodes ,for each of the answers of A create directed edge,meaning (u,v) edge says that u>v .Then in order to find the sorted sequence we must know how every 2 nodes are related or is there a path from them.The direction of this path will tell us if u>v or v<u .So we need to find is the graph  connected, which takes n(n-1)/2 steps which is in  $Ω(n^2)$

Comment: You should ask the question you are interested in.  To prove it is $\Omega(n^2)$ you can pick any two vertices that will be next to each other in the final sequence.  If you don't ask to compare those two, you won't know the sequence, so you must ask about all pairs.

Comment: Yeah,I don't know the numbers that are on the vertexes ,however at the end I know their order

Comment: If you are going to talk about it as a graph, the numbers should be on the vertices. I think it is easier to see as sorting.